# Windows Authentication working on Intranet, not working over VPN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-authentication

Using windows authentication for access control in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

We are having no issues when accessing through our intranet, but when someone connects via VPN it will not work.

I haven't been able to look at some of the offending machines off the network, but just figured I'd put it out there in case there may be some known quirks etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure what that machines is a members of your intranet domain, since you can not use windows authentication if a machine is not a members of your intranet domain.

If they are not member of your domain then you can use another security scenarios to authenticate that users:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx